# Python, Pandas - How can I get something printed in a data range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I suppose to create a function that allows user pick a range and it will print out the number within the range. however, I keep getting empty DataFrame with my code. can anyone help me?

`   import pandas as pd

```
if __name__ == "__main__":   
file_name = "sales_rossetti.xlsx"    

# Formatting numbers (e.g. $1,000,000)
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.0f}'.format

# Reading Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col = 0, convert_float = False)
print ("Welcome to Rossetti's Sales program\n")  
print ("1) Search by State")
print ("2) Search by Jan Sales")
print ("3) Search by Q2 sales")
print ("4) Exit")

my_option = input ("Please select a menu option:")


if (my_option=="2"):
    my_columns = ["Name", "City", "State", "Jan"]
    your_sales = input("please enter the minimum sale: ")
    your_sales = input("please enter the maxium sale: ")
    print (df[my_columns][df.Jan>int(your_sales)][df.Jan<int(your_sales)])`
```

Comment: well firstly you're using the same variable for your min and max range value `your_sales` is being overwritten so you should use different variables then you want `print (df.loc[(df.Jan>int(min_sales)) & (df.Jan<int(max_sales)), my_columns])`

Comment: You are saving the minimum and maximum sale to the same variable. It has to be two different variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `your_sales` variable as you're reusing it, so you should use a different variable name for the min and max params. You then need to generate a proper boolean mask using `loc` and enclosing your boolean conditions using parentheses and `&` to `and` the array of boolean values:

```
if (my_option=="2"):
    my_columns = ["Name", "City", "State", "Jan"]
    min_sales = input("please enter the minimum sale: ")
    max_sales = input("please enter the maxium sale: ")
    print (df.loc[(df.Jan > int(min_sales) ) & (df.Jan < int(max_sales)), my_columns])
```

the above should work

Comment: Thanks, that what i am looking for.